# Como pegar os valores dentro de um array?

Tags: php, array, laravel, value

```
  0 => {#557 ▼
    +"nis": 1
  }
  1 => {#561 ▼
    +"nis": 16192248487
  }
```

Tenho esse array, quero pegar os valores: **1** e **16192248487**, e joga-los em uma variável para dar um `dd` e imprimi-los na tela e mostrar apenas: **1** e **16192248487**, a linguagem que uso é php com laravel

Comment: Isso resolve? `$arr = array_map(function($el) { return $el['nis']; }, $arr);` | OBS.: $arr = nome do seu array

Comment: faz o seguinte, cria uma variavel $link = file_get_contents("URL");
    $link = json_decode($link);

    var_dump($link);

Comment: diz oque imprime.

Comment: Esses valores estão dentro de uma variavel? Foram retornados de onde? Você pode pegar os valores com um for, foreach, passando os parametros pela variavel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

é um objeto dentro do array, você tem que pegar com seletor, exemplo

```
foreach($array as $item){
  $var = $item->nis;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
<?php 
$sua_variavel = array();
$seu_array = array(
                array("nis" => 1),
                array("nis" => 16192248487)
             );

foreach($seu_array as $k => $v){   
   $sua_variavel[] = $v;    
}

dd($sua_variavel);
?>
```